# Is this a powerline insulator?

Tags: identification

Found this dumped along a trail through the woods... not attached to anything & with some other junk, but nothing that was similar. I'm curious what it is!

Its about 12" / 30cm along the top-bottom axis of the photo.

My first thought was that it is a powerline insulator. But comparing to photos online it actually is quite different in many details, especially the apparent 3 major "limbs" which come out of it -- most seem to just have 2 points of connection, and less elaborate ones than this device. (That said however, there are a lot of variations.)

The white material is a very hard glass or ceramic, the other components mainly seem to be steel.

Where the steel limbs protrude, they mate into the white body via a very dark colored material which I can't identify.

I didn't see any writing or markings at all.

I can add photos of any details if that would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Yes is a high voltage line insulator.    Or a rolling pin    ;)

Comment: Dark coloured material may well be pitch. Good insulator and there aren't many ways of sealing metal to glass (glazed ceramic)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This looks very much like the body of a fuse holder/disconnect.  It holds a fuse to isolate the distribution transformer (big grey cylinder).  The power company can also remove it to disconnect the transformer.
From: https://www.w8ji.com/power_line_noise.htm